# changing states in ionic after state.transitionTo with notify false resets the scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have an ionic app where a user can select tag and then see the tagged content, when a user arrives in the app then we show the URL as follow

http://192.168.43.149:8100/#/explore

When user taps on a tag then I change the URL from above to below

http://192.168.43.149:8100/#/explore?tag=ABCD

The code that I have to achieve this (without reloading the page) is as follow

```
     $state.transitionTo($state.current.name, {
             tag: 'ABCD'
         }, {
             notify: false
         });
```

Everything works fine till here, the tags gets selected, the content gets filtered and user sees the tag at the top along with a new URL(not reloaded) however if after selecting a tag when I click on any tile(one of the filtered ones) then I see a little glitch before the app changes the state, before changing the state I see that the tag is getting removed and  the content is resetting, when I go back from the view then I still see the URL as http://192.168.43.149:8100/#/explore?tag=ABCD but all the dependent variables on that tag gets removed and acts as http://192.168.43.149:8100/#/explore.

Comment: Could you give us your `app.js` code with your state definitions?

Comment: @nikjohn this is the state which is responsible for explore  .state('browse', {
                            url: '/explore?tag',
                            templateUrl: 'templates/explore.html'                           
                        })

Comment: I've added an answer about how to handle state data. Hopefully that helps. I was more interested in what your state specific data(which was getting reset) was, not your state definition per se.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it looks like you're losing your state information when moving from state to state. This is a common issue with Angular UiRouter/ngRouter because Angular JS is essentially stateless. The ideal way to handle this is to not bind your state data to your controllers or your state definitions. Instead, use application level services to bind data. So, an example would be:

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/users', {
        templateUrl: '/admin/tpl/users.html',
        controller: 'UsersController',
        resolve: {
          Users: function(Users) {
            return Users.get();
          }
        },
        activetab: 'users'
      })
```

In this example, you can see that no matter how you transition to the `/users` state, the `User` service that is injected into the route definition and it fetches user data every time.

This is why you should be using services to share data across states in AngularJS

Comment: thanks for providing the answer but I think the problem is with the ionic cache/history being manipulated by the transitionTo call becuase if I am removing it then everything works fine.

Comment: Could be. I don't know anything about Ionic. But from an Angular standpoint, ideally state data should be transferred using Services. Not sure if that's any different in Ionic. But glad to see your issue resolved :)

Comment: The issue still persists as this is the ionic state change issue, the state change still somehow affecting the state from where it is coming resulting in a new cached view when it should not.